# Outlook Deleted Items is clogged with redundant spam meeting decline

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am running Outlook 2013 and for the past six months or so, my Deleted Items folder has continued to fill up with the following automatic decline to a spam meeting:

```
Organizer    My name and email address
Subject      RE
Start Time   Sun 5/17/2015 2:30 PM
End Time     Sun 5/17/2015 3:30 PM
FROM VANESSA, I HAVE IMPORTANT ISSUE TO DISCUSS WITH YOU,KINDLY REPLY ME THROUGH MY PRIVATE MAIL:
alvesvanessa2012@hotmail.com AT YOUR EARLIEST CONVENIENCE.
```

These are automatically generated every 5 or 10 minutes so every day, my Deleted Items folder is filled with several hundred of these identical messages, more than a thousand of them every week.

I have created a rule that I can run manually that will permanently delete these messages after the fact, but I can't seem to make a rule that prevents them from auto-generating in the first place.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just off the top of my head, have you tried creating a rule for any meeting invites coming from the senders email address to be deleted permanently rather than moved in to your deleted items folder..?

Another option, is to have the senders email blocked ..?

Also, rather than creating the rules in your outlook client, you could use the owa - if available - to have the invites blocked before they hit your outlook client,

Comment: Unfortunately, everything I see in my deleted items folder is what I indicated in my original post. There is no user email shown!